# PayPal Subscription get transaction list

Tags: php, paypal-subscriptions

I'm building an online store.
Currently I'm on the https://api.sandbox.paypal.com

I created subscription and customer approved it. 
Everything worked as it is described in the documentation. here

> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions

Now I need to get the actual payments for this subscription to synchronise my portal with paypal payments.

I'm guessing I needed to `List transactions for subscription` as it said here:

> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_transactions

But when I'm calling this path

```
/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-T99999999999/transactions?start_time=2014-11-11T05:09:16.000Z&end_time=2020-11-11T05:09:16.000Z
```

I'm getting empty array as a response. Even if there was no transactions, I expect to have the structure, like this:

```
{
  "transactions": [],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-T99999999999/transactions?start_time=2014-11-11T05:09:16.000Z&end_time=2020-11-11T05:09:16.000Z",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm getting empty response with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem, but I found what I think can be a work around.

I can list the subscription transaction by calling the deprecated method from billing agreements.

`v1/payments/billing-agreements/{{0}}/transactions?start_date={{1}}&end_date={{2}}`

Link to the docs:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_transactions

You will get a sample response like this:

```
{
    "agreement_transaction_list": [{
        "transaction_id": "I-WBT8MCXV1XD5",
        "status": "Created",
        "transaction_type": "Recurring Payment",
        "payer_name": "Test Payer",
        "time_stamp": "2019-11-17T01:36:59Z",
        "time_zone": "GMT"
    }, {
        "transaction_id": "2V3487226T084702S",
        "status": "Updated",
        "transaction_type": "Recurring Payment",
        "amount": {
            "currency": "BRL",
            "value": "-24.90"
        },
        "fee_amount": {
            "currency": "BRL",
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        "net_amount": {
            "currency": "BRL",
            "value": "-24.90"
        },
        "payer_email": "test@email.com",
        "payer_name": "John Doe's Test Store",
        "time_stamp": "2019-11-17T01:37:01Z",
        "time_zone": "GMT"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Good to see that someone else is using the paypal subscription API. Honestly, I though it is abandoned.

Comment: I'm using transactions_get (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/v1/#transactions_get), and it is not deprecated.

Comment: I also created a case on paypal-support.com and they already agreed that it is fully their fault. PayPal developers are working on this issue right this moment.